# NUnit test of constructor fails because of missing parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, testing, nunit

I am trying to run a Unit Test using NUnit and have therefore followed a tutorial, which states the following:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestFootballplayerController
{
    [Test]
    public void FootBallPlayer_CheckingIfControllerReturnsCorrectView_MustReturnTrue()
    {
        string expected = "CreatePlayer";
        FootballplayerController controller = new FootballPlayerController();

        var result = controller.CreateIngredient() as ViewResult;

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, result.ViewName);
    }
}
```

The tutorial assumes I have a empty default constructor, but my constructor contains a parameter with my DBContext as follows:

```
    public class FootballplayerController : Controller
{
    private readonly FootballContext _context;

    public FootballplayerController(FootballContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult CreatePlayer()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Visual Studio suggests that I create an empty constructor, but in that way I think I will just test something, that shouldn't be tested, instead of the correct constructor with the parameter.

If the answer is obvious, then I must say, I am new to unit testing, and can't work a way around this. Do I have to fake a parameter?

Comment: you need to inject the context dependency

Comment: As already state you would need to provide an instance of the context (dependency) to the controller being tested.

Comment: That said, the controller should be dependent on an abstraction and not a concretion. Other wise in this case you would need to run an integration test with an in-memory database for the context to connect to. If you want to test the controller in isolation then abstract the context out.

Comment: Nkosi's comments above are the correct answer to this question

Comment: @Nkosi thank you, but does that mean, that I have to use NSubstitute on the controller? The second answer you gave me I don't understand completely, sorry. What confuses me is that I only want to check whether the controller returns the correct view, but feel that it needs a lot more work and knowledge than presumed for a rookie like me.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can just mock this class using e.g MoQ framework

```
[Test]
public void FootBallPlayer_CheckingIfControllerReturnsCorrectView_MustReturnTrue()
{
    string expected = "CreatePlayer";
    var mock = new Mock<FootballContext>();
    FootballplayerController controller = new FootballPlayerController(mock.Object);

    var result = controller.CreateIngredient() as ViewResult;

    Assert.AreEqual(expected, result.ViewName);
}
```

but you must remember that now is just empty class in this test. You can create better mock, by mocking all your DbSets, and make them IQueryable.

Comment: that makes sence, but it now gives me the following error "Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException : Can not instantiate proxy of class: WABI.Models.WABIContext.
Could not find a parameterless constructor." I guess it is still looking for that parameterless constructor as in the first place?

Comment: Ended up with creating the empty default constructor, since it didnt effect the unit test. This generates a correct Unit Test, but not the problem, though.

Comment: Do you have parameterless constructor for FootballContext? I remember that i had similar problem with this and Microsoft DI.

Comment: I ended up creating a parameterless constructor, since finding a way around took too much time and from the comments above it seemed to be a task above my skills. The parameterless constructor solved the problem.